# Using carmen gem with rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.1

What I am trying to do is show the 2 letter abbreviation code of the countries, i.e 'US'.

After the country is selected I need to show its state or province.
but I am having a problem.

My code looks like

```
<%= f.select :country_code, region_options_for_select(only_us_and_france) %>
```

and define this in helper:

```
def only_us_and_france
    Carmen::Country.all.select{|c| %w{US FR}.include?(c.code)}
end
```

I am using Rails 4.1.0.

Comment: Do you mean to ask that you want to have two `selects` in an HTML form. And choosing a particular country will populate the other select with the sub regions of that specific country?

Comment: yeah exactly i need this.

Comment: But I didn't understand why the helper is named "only_us_and_canada"

Comment: Its just a name of a helper.

Comment: re organize thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by :

**Step1: Generated migration**

```
rails g migration addStateCodeFieldToAccounts state_code:string
```

**Step2: Define a method inside controller**

```
def subregion_options
    render partial: 'subregion_select'
end
```

**Step3: Declare in routes**

```
resources :accounts do
    collection do
      get 'subregion_options'
    end
  end
```

**Step4: In view**

```
<div class="input-control select state_input" data-role="input-control">
   <%= f.select :country, region_options_for_select(only_us_and_france) %>
</div>
<div class="input-control select state_input" data-role="input-control">
  <%= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country} %>
</div>
```

**Step5: Make partial subregion_select**

```
<div id="account_state_code_wrapper">
  <% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %>
  <% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %>

  <% if country.nil? %>
    <em>Please select a country above</em>
  <% elsif country.subregions? %>
    <%= subregion_select(:order, :state_code, parent_region) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= text_field(:order, :state_code) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Step6: In my js file written this**

```
 $('select#account_detail_country').change(function(){
    selectWrapper = $('#account_state_code_wrapper')
    countryCode = $(this).val()
    url = "/account_details/subregion_options?parent_region="+countryCode
    console.log(url)
    selectWrapper.load(url)
  });
```

yeah and it works :) Hope this will help you.